# How to use iOS PDF reader API to view remote PDF files via URL?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf-viewer

I have used [iOS PDF Reader Core](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) API to create an iPhone app that displays PDF files on my device file system..

My doubt is how to use this API to view remote PDF files by giving a URL path.
The `ReaderDocument` object only accepts file paths to be specified.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do this. I'm not very familiar with the framework you linked to, but I work full-time on the PSPDFKit iOS PDF SDK. To render PDF's on iOS, they need to be fully downloaded. You basically create a CGPDFDocument at some point either via

```
CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(...)
(or)
CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(...)
```

Now CoreGraphics will throw out some cryptic error 15 if you try to feed CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL with a remote URL (although it does work for /localhost/ remote URLs)

You theoretically could write a CGDataProvider that downloads the document on the fly, but the trouble is that iOS still will read and parse the whole PDF before it can display it - and I went through the trouble of writing a custom provider myself (one that supports AES256 and decrypts PDF content on the fly for extra security). It's really tricky to get it right.

**tl,dr: You need to download the PDF.** For example with this neat [AFNetworking extension](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) I wrote - it even supports resume.